# No trailing closures support for methods with default parameter values?

Tags: swift

You can drop the code below into playgrounds.

```
import UIKit

class MyClass {
  func foo(a: String, b: () -> ()) {
    b()
  }
  func bar(a: String = "a", b: () -> ()) {
    b()
  }
}

let object = MyClass()

object.foo("x") { () -> () in
  println("foo")
}

object.bar() { () -> () in
  println("foo")
}
```

`object.bar()` call produces `Missing argument for parameter 'b' in call`

The question is: am I doing something wrong, or trailing closures are not supported in methods with default parameter values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does look like a problem with trailing closures - this code works:

```
object.bar(b: {  () -> () in
    println("foo") 
})
```

However if the external name is removed:

```
func bar(a: String = "a", _ b: () -> ()) {
    b()
}
```

this no longer works:

```
object.bar({  () -> () in
    println("foo")
})
```

Moreover using a function having a string as the 2nd parameter:

```
func test( val1: String = "a",  val2: String) {        
}
```

the default parameter is correctly assigned, so this succeeds:

```
test("me")
```

which is a different behavior than using closures.

Conclusion: a method or function with parameter(s) having default value and a trailing closure does not work if at least one of the parameters with default value is not specified. Avoiding the trailing closure the function works only if the parameter has external name.

Comment: Good points. Thanks. I'll wait a bit and unless someone comes up with anything more I'll accept your answer. Do you see that as a missing feature or a bug?

Comment: Taking into account that the case without external names doesn't work with closures, I would consider the non-trailing case a bug. It seems like the compiler tries to assign the closure to the first parameter with default value, ignoring its type. As for the trailing case, I don't know... it's possible that's a wanted behavior, but not documented.