# Swift 3 / How to solve: "Ambiguous use of 'authorize(_:completion:)'"

Tags: swift, swift3

*Please don't close because of duplicate of "Ambiguous use of...". Even with intense research I was not able to find any similar threads solving my issue.*

I'm updating a project to Swift 3 and am stuck at a compiler error:

> Ambiguous use of 'authorize(_:completion:)'

Code:

```
func connectToInstagram() {

    let auth: NSMutableDictionary = ["client_id": INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID,
                                     SimpleAuthRedirectURIKey: INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URI]

    SimpleAuth.configuration()["instagram"] = auth

    SimpleAuth.authorize("instagram") { (anyObject, error) in // error here

        if anyObject != nil {...
```

[SimpleAuth](https://github.com/calebd/SimpleAuth) is a Framework to handle Social Media authentication written in Objective C.

SimpleAuth:

```
open class SimpleAuth : NSObject {

    open class func authorize(_ provider: String!, completion: SimpleAuth.SimpleAuthRequestHandler!)
```

[image]

SimpleAuthRequestHandler:

```
public typealias SimpleAuthRequestHandler = (Any?, Error?) -> Swift.Void

public let SimpleAuthPresentInterfaceBlockKey: String
public let SimpleAuthDismissInterfaceBlockKey: String
```

[image]

I have tried to change the line to:

```
_ = SimpleAuth.authorize("instagram") { (anyObject: Any?, error: Error?) in

_ = SimpleAuth.authorize("instagram", completion: { (anyObject: Any?, error: Error?) in
```

But just as expected, it didn't changed anything. What am I missing? Help is very appreciated.

Build Log:

[image]

```
xy/InstagramVC.swift:409:9: error: ambiguous use of 'authorize(_:completion:)'
        SimpleAuth.authorize("instagram") { (any: Any?, error: Error?) -> Swift.Void in 
        ^
SimpleAuth.SimpleAuth:24:21: note: found this candidate
    open class func authorize(_ provider: String!, completion: SimpleAuth.SimpleAuthRequestHandler!)
                    ^
SimpleAuth.SimpleAuth:34:21: note: found this candidate
    open class func authorize(_ provider: String!, options: [AnyHashable : Any]! = [:], completion: SimpleAuth.SimpleAuthRequestHandler!)
```

Comment: Try to check build log, or just build from command line.  As far as I remember compiler can give you the list of offenders that produce the ambiguity.

Comment: @AntonBronnikov I have edited the question with the build log information

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but there is an ambiguity b/w those two methods (the one with `options` argument has a default value, so it can be reduced to exactly the same signature as the other one).  Try to remove the default value (this bit: ` = [:]`),

Comment: you meant delete ` = [:]` from the `open class SimpleAuth : NSObject` class? I can't. For some reason I can't edit this class. at all. I have even tried to restart xcode. perhaps because it's objective c?

Comment: @AntonBronnikov thank you very much for your help.

Comment: If you can't edit this, then maybe file an issue with the owner of that framework.  This is something that certainly has to be fixed.  Meanwhile, yes, use that workaround with explicitly passing the `options` argument.

Comment: Is this the same issue as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27332655/no-trailing-closures-support-for-methods-with-default-parameter-values ? In that case *not* using the trailing closure syntax would should solve the problem: `SimpleAuth.authorize("instagram", completion: { (anyObject, error) in ... })`

Comment: @AntonBronnikov I have filed an Issue at the owner's github.

Comment: @MartinR this solution was tried and did not worked. passing the options argument as empty dict does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the API. They provide these two functions:

`open class func authorize(_ provider: String!, completion: SimpleAuth.SimpleAuthRequestHandler!)`

and

`open class func authorize(_ provider: String!, options: [AnyHashable : Any]! = [:], completion: SimpleAuth.SimpleAuthRequestHandler!)`

but as you can see the `options` argument of the second function has been given a default argument (`[:]`).  So when you *don't* specify the `options` parameter, the compiler can't tell which function you want to call.

This means the first function can't be used. You'll always have to use the second function and pass an explicit `options` argument. So:

`authorize("instagram", options: [:]) { (any: Any?, error: Error?) -> Void in ... }`

It's probably worth filing a bug with the `SimpleAuth` framework author(s).